# By group, change column values based on whether any row in group takes specific value

Tags: r

I'm trying to make this data wide instead of long. Rather than recasting (which seems to get tricky based on the dates), I'm trying another approach. For each unique candidate, I'd like to populate new fields called "Felony1" "Felony1Date", "Misdemeanor1" and "Misdemeanor1Date" (May add more felonies and misdemeanors, but that's irrelevant for now.) (Also numbers greater than 1 we can treat as 1.)

```
CandidateID Conviction.Date Felony Misdemeanor
1      1234      2007-09-27     0           3
2      1234      2009-02-09     0           2
3      1234      2013-01-16     10          0
4      1234      1993-03-15     1           0
5      5678      2006-04-27     1           0
6      5678      2011-01-11     0           1
```

I'm looking for a way to check if a Candidate has a value > 0 in the Misdemeanor/Felony column, and if so, create a new column "Felony1"/"Misdemeanor1" that takes a 1. Also, "Felony1Date"/"Misdemeanor1Date" should take the date from the corresponding row. I'd like this all to happen in the first row for each candidate, as I show below.

```
CandidateID   Fel1 Fel1Date Misd1    Misd1Date    Misd2    Misd2Date
1      1234      1  2013-01-16  1    2007-09-27     1      2009-02-09
2      5678      1  2006-04-27  1    2011-01-11     0       NA
```

I've tried using mutate and data.table packages. However I couldn't get either  to place the value for the new column in the correct row.

```
df <- group_by(CandidateID) %>% mutate(Felony1 = ifelse(Felony > 0, 1, 0)) 
df[, F := 1[Felony > 0], by=CandidateID]
```

Edited based on Akrun's suggestion

Comment: Can you show the full expected output based on the example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% arrange(CandidateID, Conviction.Date) %>% group_by(CandidateID) %>% slice(1) %>% mutate(Felony1 = ifelse(Felony > 0, 1, 0), Felony1Date = Conviction.Date, Misdemeanor1 = ifelse(Misdemeanor > 0, 1, 0), Misdemeanor1Date = Conviction.Date)
```

Comment: So close! The problem is that it's assigning the misdemeanor and felony conviction dates according to whatever is in the first row -- rather than looking up the row for which there is the relevant conviction. I was trying to subset mutate using a logical vector for the nth occurrence of felony or conviction in each row, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.